# Can't get JSON from a GET request

Tags: java, web-services, rest, playframework

New to Play! Framework and web development in general, I'm trying to do a simple REST GET to a web service and just get some straight-forward JSON in response. Typing the URL into a browser, I get a perfect response, with nicely formatted JSON. Calling it via code, it just blows up:

```
   WS.WSRequest wsRequest = WS.url( serviceURL );
   wsRequest.timeout( timeoutTime );
   wsRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   wsRequest.headers.put( "Content-type","application/json" );
   wsRequest.mimeType = "application/json"; 

   WS.HttpResponse response = wsRequest.get();
   String graphServiceResponse = response.getJson().toString();
```

Everything executes fine, until the last line where it throws an exception and errors out. I know I have what looks like a lot of redundant code; those are my attempts to fix it. Like I said, typing the "serviceURL" into a browser, it works fine.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which exception does it throw?

Comment: Not sure (can't debug into code), but it gives back a HTTP 500 response.

Comment: I actually solved this, but the system won't let me post my own answer for a few hours yet. Will update when I can!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, solved this. Just omitted all the sets and such, added authentication and it worked perfectly. Weird.

```
   String stringResponse = "";
   try {
      // execute GET to graph service
      WS.WSRequest wsRequest = WS.url( serviceURL ).authenticate( USERNAME, PASSWORD );
      WS.HttpResponse response = wsRequest.get();
      stringResponse = response.getString();

      ... more cool stuff ...
```

Thanks for looking!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried and found this below code working. 10000 is the timeout parameter in ms.

```
    String baseUrl = "your url";

    F.Promise<WSResponse> response = ws.url(baseUrl)
            .setQueryParameter(param, value)
            .get();

    return response.get(10000).asJson().toString();
```